# Is it possible to initialize the state of a component with API data before the initial mounting of the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

In my react application I'd like to initialize the state of my component using API data. One way that would work is to make the API call in useEffect() and then set the state after the API call, but this would occur after the initial mounting of the component.

I'm just wondering if there are other ways to initialize the state before the initial mounting of the component? Here is what I tried and it doesn't work.

```
async function getAns() {
    let output = [];
    //make api calls and assign data to output
    //.......
    return output;
  };

const [playersList, setPlayersList] = useState(getAns());
```

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: You could wrap your component in another component that makes the api call and conditionally renders this component

Comment: You could do it in the parent component and pass it as a prop.

Comment: Is there a specific issue you are trying to resolve or are you *just wondering* if something is possible? Short answer, yes, it is possible to initialize the state of a component with API data. It is basically possible to initialize the state of a component with *any* value you like. It is a very common React pattern to use the `useEffect` hook to dispatch calls to fetch data that is stored in local component state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use async-await with your funtion and load the components only when the state has the response data from your API call.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [playerList, setPlayerList] = useState();

 async function getAns(){

   let output = await //make api calls and assign data to output
    
   return setPlayerList(output);

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAns();
  }, [])

return (
  {playerList && (
    // Component jsx elements
)}
)
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: what is `return setPlayerList(output);` ? What exactly is returned here?

Comment: Just verified, it's nothing. setState returns `undefined`.